# Dependency checks in JBPM workflows

Tags: drools, jbpm

All,

I am using JBoss JBPM and Drools.
The workflows are loaded to the KnowlwegdeBuilder as resources. There are multiple sub-processes (or child processes) that are invoked from parent processes.

is there any way to check if these child-processes were loaded prior to loading the parent process? 
i.e. some kind of parent-child dependency check.

Reason is - if there are any missing sub-processes (child processes) - I know about this only at run time (when my workflow is actually running), is there a way to determine this prior to actually firing the workflow?

regards
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to check that I'm afraid. Because the sub process reference can be a process variable which can also be calculated at runtime it is something difficult to check. Parsing the Process to find the sub process references if they are not variables can be done fairly easy. 
Which version of jBPM are you using?

Cheers